# How can I make a struct with a constant parameter that may be only known at runtime?

Tags: rust

At the moment I have my own integer type which works like this:

```
let x = Integer::new(12);
```

Now I want to work with integers mod n (and be able to properly overload binary operations), so I would like something that works like this:

```
let X = IntegerMod<11>;
let x = X::new(12);
```

Then 12 is reduced mod 11 so x = 1.

I can do this using const generics but then the modulus needs to be known at compile time and I can't have a function output some `IntegerMod<n>` where n is determined at runtime (which I would like to have).

What is the best way to get this behavior?

Comment: What's wrong with just doing something like `X::new(value, mod)` -- eg, `X::new(12, 11)`?

Comment: A "constant parameter only known at runtime" is a variable.

Comment: @user2722968 true, I guess I meant "constant generic" but I was trying to avoid that since const generics are already a thing and don't suit my needs

Comment: As I know you can't use a primitive or value inside the angle brackets, because that space is for types and is used in compilation time.

Comment: @Herohtar That works but is there no way to have the modulus stored and accessible later? I wanted syntax like `let X = IntegerMod<n>` so that I could either create elements with `new` or work with directly with the ring of integers mod n (something like `X * X` for a direct product, etc.)

Comment: @ogranada Thanks, that seems to be the case. I'm open to other syntax, I just want to keep the elements and actual ring of integers mod n separate and keep the `new` constructor so it doesn't stray too far from the syntax I'm already using. See my previous comment as well

Comment: Store the value inside the `IntegerMod` struct and use it as an `Integer` factory, then you can do `let X = IntegerMod::new(11)` and `let x = X.build(12)`

Comment: It seems like hiding the value like that would make things confusing though, because you have no way of knowing what the modulus was without potentially tracing really far back through your code.

Comment: @Herohtar thanks, I might use your suggestion. I agree hiding it might be confusing, but it's the standard for most math software like Sage, which has the syntax: `R = IntegerModRing(n)` and coercion like `R(m)` to get m mod n. I'm struggling to get a decently close syntax in Rust for this as well as lots of other structures like matrix rings and finite fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a sort of factory function approach, where an `IntegerMod` instance can be created giving it the modulus value, which acts as the factory for `Integer` values. The underlying type can be generic.

Usage could look something like this:

```rust
fn main() 
{
    let im = IntegerMod::fact(5);
    
    println!("{:?}", im.new(111)); // Prints `Integer { value: 1 }`.
}
```

IntegerMod as an Integer producer.

```rust
use std::ops::Rem;

struct IntegerMod<T> 
{ 
    modulus: T,    
}

impl<T> IntegerMod<T>
where 
    T: Rem<Output = T> + Copy,
{
    fn fact(modulus: T) -> Self
    {
        IntegerMod { modulus }
    }
    
    // Maybe name this something different. But keeping with the example...
    fn new(&self, value: T) -> Integer<T>
    {
        Integer::new(value % self.modulus)
    }
}
```

Integer:

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Integer<T> 
{ 
    value: T,
}

impl<T> Integer<T>
{
    fn new(value: T) -> Self
    {
        Integer { value }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I think this is the approach I will use (also recommended by Herohtar in the comments).